# Error: "Command "maximizeWindow" is not yet implemented" using webdriverIO v6

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I have a project on *webdriverIOv5* which I have tried to upgrade to version 6.
But when calling `browser.maximizeWindow()`, then I get this as an error:

> ERROR @wdio/sync: Error: Command "maximizeWindow" is not yet implemented

Here is my demo project https://github.com/mareru/webdriverIO-shop-demo.
Does anybody know how to fix this?
I did find some similar references on gitter but according to them, this should work.
I don't get what am I doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading and never managed to figure it out, so would be interested if there is a solution too. I ended up using  browser.setWindowSize(1920,1080) in the short term to get it set at a consistent size.

Comment: @DaveGordon I get this strange behavior with the browser.setWindowSize(300,700). Inner browser area is resized, but outer browser window keeps hanging. Check this image: https://monosnap.com/file/SBQuydAOE3mV5dtLbA07PWJx0SsRJf Do you know why is this happening? Does it behave the same for you too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maximizeWindow` was removed when chromedriver switched from json wire to W3C protocol and reimplemented a couple of versions ago.

Make sure to use the latest version of chromedriver. You have to configure `selenium-standalone` service according to https://webdriver.io/docs/selenium-standalone-service.html#configuration in your config https://github.com/mareru/webdriverIO-shop-demo/blob/master/src/wdio.conf.ts#L95

Verified in my own example repo https://gitlab.com/bar_foo/wdio-cucumber-typescript/-/blob/master/config/wdio.CHROME.conf.ts

Comment: thanks, I made the changes based on your repo and it worked, window size changed